# React Native Firestore infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get user data from firestore using a documentSnapshot, i can get the data but it is stuck in an infinite loop, updating the user data,

here's the code

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
export default function HomeScreen() {
     const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
     const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('');

     useEffect(() => {
      firestore()
           .collection('users')
           .doc(user.uid)
           .get()
           .then(documentSnapshot => {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                     setCurrentUser(documentSnapshot.data())
                }
           })

 })
 return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
           <Title>{currentUser.displayName}</Title>
           <FormButton
                modeValue='contained'
                title='Logout'
                onPress={() => logout()} />
      </View>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `setCurrentUser` you're forcing a rerender (because this is a state variable).  Your `useEffect` then fires again, which calls `setCurrentUser` again, and so on, causing the infinite loop.

To prevent this, you should set a list of variables that `useEffect` should listen for before firing.  You can do this by passing a second parameter to `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your function call
}, [/* list of state/prop variables to respond to */])
```

If you want `useEffect` to fire only once, similar to `componentDidMount`, you may pass an empty array.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

In your case it seems you may want to place `user` in this array, since that is the only variable your firestore call relies on.  If `user.uid` has not changed, there is no reason to fire this effect again.